# Linear Gradient from bottom to top

Tags: wpf, xaml, lineargradientbrush

I need an `Ellipse` with a linear gradient from bottom(pink) to top(red).

```
<Ellipse Width="200" Height="200">    
    <Ellipse.Fill>

        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="1,0" > 

            <GradientStop Color="Pink" Offset="0" />

            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1" />

        </LinearGradientBrush>

    </Ellipse.Fill>    
</Ellipse>
```

The above code shows a gradient from left bottom to top right.

I need the gradient to move from left middle to top middle.

I tried changing the starting and end point with no success. Is there another property that can be used?

It has to be a linear gradient on a ellipse. I cannot use a radial gradient here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

gradient from Bottom to Top (vertical)

```
<LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="0,0">
```

gradient from left middle to top middle

```
<LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="0.5,0">
```

Answer (score 9):

Visual representation of how it works

[image]

[image]

[image]